# jQuery Ajax success not being invoked

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

Here is my code,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: action,
    data: params,
    success: function() {
        alert("Success");
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("error occurred");
    }  });
```

I have a form inside a modal dialog window, on submission i would like to stay inside the dialog rather than return to original window. I have solved this issue elsewhere by surrounding the contents of the dialog with a div, and then calling #div.load("some page") in the success portion.

However, for some reason on this page the success portion does not get executed at all, although the form submits correctly, the dialog closes and the request is resubmitted to the action url of the form. I have tried to make the request asynchronous but that did not help.

I cannot understand why the same code that works on another feature is not working here.
Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Thanks,
Natasha

Answer (score 2):

Purely a guess, because there's not code enough to tell, but I would say that your ajax function is being triggered by an event that would ordinarily cause the form to post back to the server.  Try returning false in the handler that generates the ajax request to stop the default event handling action.

```
$('input[type=submit]').click( function() {
     $.ajax( ... );
     return false;
});
```

If this is the case, then the ajax call is being made, but before the success handler can be invoked, the page unloads as a result of the post back.

Comment: Ok, I did that, and you are right the modal does not close now, but the alert in the success portion still does not come up. And the server side portion is no longer invoked either.

Comment: Time for a little firebug debugging then.  Can you check that the request is actually made and, if so, what the response is?

Comment: Perhaps, post more code?  It might help to know how "actions" and "params" are set.

Comment: @natasha: What was it? I have a similar issue and I can't figure out what's happening.

Thanks.