# success / error callback(s) not being invoked after 'fetch' (on Backbone.Collection)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

I'm currently having a strange problem with (or around) Backbone. I have a Backbone collection object for which I put custom success and error callbacks.

A) ----> Working

```
    Fubars = Backbone.Collection.extend({ 
      
      url: "/listfubar",
      model: Fubar,
      fetchS: function() {
        fetch(  { success : sFn, 
                    error : eFn, 
                    statusCode : cFn 
        }); 
      },  
    })
    
    var fbars = new Fubars(); 
    fbars.fetchS();
```

B) ----> Breaking

```
    afterPoll = function() {   
        fbars.fetchS()
    }
```

This works fine when `Fubars.fetchS` is being invoked through a regular JavaScript file A). However, I'm having a problem when `fetchS` (and supplied callbacks) is itself invoked from an '[ajaxPoll](http://www.nickriggs.com/posts/simple-ajax-polling-plugin-for-jquery/)' callback B) . `fetchS` is properly called, the callbacks all exist, and the network call is made through Backbone.sync > JQuery.ajax. But the success, error, or statusCode callbacks are never invoked (again, the network call definitely goes out, and returns successfully).

Has anyone run into this? I can only think that the success and error callbacks might somehow be disappearing, when `afterPoll` exits. But `fubars` is a global object, so that doesn't make any sense.

I've looked at similar posts ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363970/jquery-ajax-success-not-being-invoked)), but not solving my problem. Any insights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if the `fetch()` needs a reference to the `fbars` instance.  What happens when you do `afterPoll = _.bind(fbars.fetchS, fbars);  afterPoll();`?

Comment: Do you have your console window open to see if you are getting any exceptions?

Comment: You should clarify if the callbacks are not invoked at all or they don't work. My bet is that they are invoked, but they don't work because they don't have the right "this", and you should use bind or bindAll to set the current object as "this" in the callbacks as well http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bindAll

Comment: no exceptions; the poll callback worked, but not the later 'success' callback for fetch. ended up solving this problem by going around it > 'this' reference disappeared. When the polling callback invokes fetchS, its' 'success' callback disappears after the network call > I did try to 'bindAll' this to fetch, fetchS, sync (the Bb fn that actually invokes $.ajax), etc, but nothing worked > ended up directly calling $.ajax after polling, and manually setting the Fubars collection with the result > didn't try hyperslug's suggestion - an interesting trial. really want to know where 'this' gets lost

Comment: Why you don't use the original fetch method of Backbone.collection passing the success and error callbacks? like this: Fubars.fetch({success:sFn,error:eFn}); In http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-fetch says that you can pass arguments to fetch method..

Answer (score 0):

do this for fetch..

```
    
    (function fetch(){success:...,error:... }).call();
    or
    (function fetch(){return {success:...,error:...}
     }).call();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect, problem may be due to the missing **this**.

Try to replace this statement:

```
    fetch(  { success : sFn, 
                error : eFn, 
                statusCode : cFn 
    });
```

with this statement:

```
    this.fetch(  { success : sFn, 
                error : eFn, 
                statusCode : cFn 
    });
```